# Use Azure Devops PAT API with a Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to automatically update pats expiration date on azure devops.

I followed MS Guide on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops

This works fine but it requires user manual login

So i tried with powershell 7 Connect-AzAccount command instead:

```
$azureAplicationId = "[app_id]"
$azureTenantId = "[tenant_id]"
$azurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString "[app_secret]" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId,$azurePass)

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -Tenant $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

Then

```
(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token
```

And i do get the bearer token but when i use it on Postman:
[image]

I think this is related to the fact that user impersonation permission on Azure appears to be only available as a delegated permission, nor a Application Permission:
[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your situation and your error message on "401" response, tested by my side, this user sign in process cannot be bypassed when I tested by following the doc you shared, at last, it is still needed to login with your user account first.

[image]

So, it is suggested that you can directly login first with powershell 7 Connect-AzAccount command.

And here is the getting token script sample in Postman to update the PAT as below, you can check your Body to see whether they are all correct.

1.First, you should Login with a **user account** which has the permission in your DevOps org (Owner or PCA) with command `Connect-AzAccount` and with command `(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token`  to get the bearer token.

[image]

2.Then, you can 'GET' to List the required body like "**authorizationId**" via the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

[image]

3.After that, 'PUT' to achieve the PAT token with "Body" modified as below:

```
{
    "displayName": "1111",
    "validTo": "2022-11-25T08:08:17.8166667Z",
    "scope": "app_token",
    "targetAccounts": [
        "782xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0ecca5"
    ],
    "validFrom": "2022-12-25T08:08:28.3266667Z",
    "authorizationId": "5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx50e",
    "token": null
}
```

The updating PAT response will be like as the pic below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @RoyWang-MSFT. So, currently there is no way to bypass the sign in process for the PATs API, right? It would be nice to have this feature

Comment: @Rodri Hi! Yes, you're right. Also, regarding this limit for your Azure Devops PATs API with a Service Principal requirement, you could create a feature request via:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

And if the answer can help resolve your concern, you may consider accepting it. It will be helpful to other members who has the same issue.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. In item 3 the validFrom if after validTo. It's not clear what changed from the PUT request.